# Did you know System.Collections.Generic.List is implemented with an array?

Tags: .net, collections

I had a performance problem today that showed up after some profiling.  Calls to List<>.RemoveAt(0) were taking a long time.  I'd assumed System.Collections.Generic.List would be implemented with a list data structure, but actually its implemented as an array.

Does anyone else find that surprising?

Comment: @Frank Schwieterman: No, not at all, and `List<T>` never really *hid* it, given the fact that it has a Capacity property which gets/sets the buffer size (and the buffer is an array).  I am curious what you thought it would be?  A linked list of items?  That would be wasteful, as multiple add/delete operations would cause considerable pressure on the GC for large lists.

Comment: @Frank: you've heard of Reflector, right? For the past five years, anyone who wanted to know how `List<T>` is implemented could go look at it. You know they released the sources for debugging purposes? You could single-step into `List<T>.Remove()` if you want to see how it works.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one to have found some of the .NET Collections naming to be somewhat... unexpected. Absolutely I expected a container named List to be implemented as a linked list, and was also surprised way back when to find that it wasn't.

Comment: @John Yes thats how I found this piece of information in the first place.  Reflector is ftw.

Comment: @csj: If an array is not a type of list, what is? It's more so than a linkedlist, which could also be named chain.

Comment: I guess from my math days I would rather call what some people consider a 'list' a 'sequence' (effectively, an IEnumerable).  From working with the STL way back in the day, a "List" was effectively a sequence implemented as a linked list.  I can adjust my understanding fine :) don't need to argue that the view is correct or not.  It just caught me by surprise.  And I had seen the capacity field in the class, again experienced dissonance but didn't look into it at the time.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: Several years ago, through my newbie eyes, looking at the collections available in .NET, I would have anticipated that a collection called List would have been a linked list. Like Frank has just said, however, "I can adjust my undertanding fine."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's similar to the C++ standard std::vector type, as well as a generic replacement for the C# ArrayList type, which has "Array" in its name. If you want linked list behavior, use the LinkedList type.